# Merging MySQL database rows into columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a database with the structure, where id and name are the key

| id | name | cp | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | abc | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | abc | 3 | 12 |
| 2 | xyx | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | xyx | 2 | 11 |
| 2 | xyx | 2 | 13 |

and I need a query to merge it into a new table structure where its ID and name are only 1 row with the following structure, with time in each column value.

| id | name | cp1 | cp2 | cp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 10 | 3 | 12 |
| 2 | xyz | 12 | 11 | 13 |

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you show what type of query you've already come up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your table 3 times:

```
SELECT   m.id as id,
         m.name as name,
         m1.time as cp1,
         m2.time as cp2,
         m3.time as cp3
FROM mytable m            -- This is the base table
LEFT JOIN mytable m1 ON   -- This is a join to take cp1 if present
          m.id = m1.id
          AND m.name = m1.name
          AND m1.cp = 1
LEFT JOIN mytable m2 ON   -- This is a join to take cp2 if present
          m.id = m2.id
          AND m.name = m2.name
          AND m2.cp = 2
LEFT JOIN mytable m3 ON   -- This is a join to take cp3 if present
          m.id = m3.id
          AND m.name = m3.name
          AND m3.cp = 3
GROUP BY m.id,
         m.name,
         m1.time,
         m2.time,
         m3.time
```

It has been joined 3 times to be sure that if you have any of cp1, cp2 or cp3 null it works. If you are sure that there are no rows absence for cp1 cp2 cp3 you can leave just 2 inner joins (instead of 3 left joins).

Note that this solution works with any relational database, not only mysql because there is no reference to special function of the database, but only standard SQL joins.

Comment: This solution is not wrong and technically correct. BUT it introduces unnecessary overhead, both in syntax and execution. See below for the usual implementation using conditional aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a typo in your data and the 6th record should have a `cp` of 3, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT  t.id,
        t.name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN cp = 1 THEN t.time END) AS cp1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN cp = 2 THEN t.time END) AS cp2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN cp = 3 THEN t.time END) AS cp3
FROM T AS t
GROUP BY t.id, t.name;
```

If you are guaranteed to have one record per combination of `id`, `name` and `cp` then the `MAX` is largely irrelevant because you are taking the `MAX` of just one row, so it is deterministic. If you could have duplicates then you may need additional logic to determine which of the multiple records should be returned, or if you want to apply different aggregation (e.g. `SUM`).

**[Example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kd7bzqZoUKogN3scoWcLPs/2)**

Comment: This is how pivots in SQL are usually built. The JOIN variant in the accepted answer should only be applied where conditional aggregation is nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

GROUP BY will summarize each id and name. And GROUP_CONCAT will give you the list of cp's. Here's a sample query.

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(cp) as cps
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id, name
```

Comment: In this example, the individual cps are presented as a comman seperated list in a single column, not as seperate columns as OP requested.